# How can I detect an emoji insert event from the OS X character viewer and iOS emoji keyboard in Javascript/Redactor?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, nstextview, emoji, redactor

I'm having trouble getting Redactor (a WYSIWYG contenteditable web editor by Imperavi) to recognize the **character insert event** that results from the OS X Character Viewer and inline emoji palettes, as well as the iOS emoji palette.

Redactor doesn't sync the change until I add, say, a space or trigger a paste event. Then it gets picked up and saved as one would expect. Forcing a sync before submitting the form doesn't appear to pick the character up either (or I'm doing it wrong).

Is there a particular event associated with the insert triggered by these OS X/iOS palettes, or would you have some workaround ideas for getting Redactor to notice the character?

Try it at http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/placeholder/ ; click inside the text entry area, invoke the emoji palette using <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> and click an emoji to insert it. The placeholder not disappearing is one indicator that the insert didn't register.

Answer (score 0):

The DOMCharacterDataModified event notices the insert and can be used to trigger a .redactor('code.sync').

So I set this up as an event listener in initCallback and use it when the underlying textarea used by Redactor appears empty; this because even after the sync, content consisting solely of emoji doesn't necessarily get synced going forward. (When the textarea has content, syncing appears to include emoji).